# How can I load a Image from a file, then an image to a bitmap?

Tags: c#, image, file, drawing

I have a file location on my file system.

I need to first load the file into a System.Drawing.Image, then I need to load the Image into a bitmap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try the `Image.FromFile` and `Bitmap.FromFile` methods. if you specifically need to convert an `Image` instance into a `Bitmap` instance, I think you can pass in an `Image` object in the `Bitmap` constructor.

Answer (score 4):

Skip the "load into an Image" step, it's a one-liner:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(path);
```

Bitmap is derived from Image, you can use it where-ever an Image object is required.